# NDK download and location problem on ubuntu

Tags: python, android, kivy, buildozer

I try to use buildozer to make an android app using python, kivy.

When I run the code

```
buildozer android debug deploy run
```

I got this error:

```
# Recommended android's NDK version by p4a is: 17c
# Android NDK is missing, downloading
# Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-ndk-r17c-linux-x86_64.zip
```

So, I download NDK- version 17c, manually and move the unzip file into: /.buildozer/android/platform/
still, it does not work and have the same error.
So, How can I check the exact directory that my ndk should be in there?  Any suggestion to fix this problem? great thanks in advance

Comment: You shouldn't have to do the download manually, buildozer even says it is downloading the NDK. You should be able to just let it do the download and install.

Comment: Within my `~/.buildozer/android/platform/` directory, I have the directory `android-ndk-r17c`.

Comment: Thanks. I just make a directory with this name and put all the ndk in it. It fix. great thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it turns out that google banned my country
so I used a VPN and the problem solved.